# VueJS API error in production mode (npm run build)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm building 2 applications that transfer data through an API. It works perfectly until I use npm run build. The strange thing is, I get an error (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)) and my screen freezes for 30 seconds when I'm on the page that makes the request, but when I visit the API url everything seems to work perfectly.

Using CORS browser extension, but no result.

function in vue component:

```
fetchData() {
      console.log('fetching', import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ROOT_URL_TO_API + '/checklist/' + this.name);
      axios.get(import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ROOT_URL_TO_API + '/checklist/' + this.name)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.data = response.data;

            if (this.name === 'klusjes binnen' || this.name === 'klusjes buiten') {
              this.activeAccordion = this.filteredCheckListItems.length;
              this.klusjes = true;
            }
          })
    },
```

.env:

```
VITE_APP_ROOT_URL_TO_API=http://mcdo-app-desktop.test/api
```

PHP function it directs to:

```
public function singleChecklist($name) {
        $checkList = Checklist::where('name', $name)->with('checklistItem', 'checklistItem.listItem')->first();

        $checkList->checklistItem->each(function ($list) {

            $options = [
                "ssl" => [
                    "verify_peer"=>false,
                    "verify_peer_name"=>false,
                ]
            ];

            $list->image = base64_encode(file_get_contents(url('/') . '/storage/images/' . $list->icon_url,  false, stream_context_create($options)));
        });
        return response()->json($checkList);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproductible example, see : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Don't use a CORS extension, fix it properly to begin with. Try with an HTTP client to see if you can replicate the issue. Also, not sure if your backend is replying with a JSON or HTML response here, check that one too.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the API works perfectly when you visit the URL directly, but it fails when you build and run the application, it might indicate that there is an issue with how you're handling the environment variables in your Vue.js application.

I suggest looking in the network tab for the request that's causing the 404 error and inspecting the URL. You also need to add a catch statement to capture any errors that may occur during the request.

My guess would be that
`import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ROOT_URL_TO_API + '/checklist/' + this.name`
is not a valid URL.